# How to upsert into a table without setting an index?

Tags: postgresql

Suppose the following setup:

```
create table chat_message (
  id serial primary key,
  message_id bigint unique not null, -- id from third party service
  message_type varchar(255) unique not null
);
```

I can upsert into this table like this:

```
-- insert first record
insert into chat_message
values(1, 1234, 'start_message');

-- upsert
insert into chat_message (message_id, message_type)
values(1260, 'start_message')
on conflict (message_type)
do update set message_id = 1260;
```

This works fine, but I need to structure the table like this:

```
create table chat_message (
  id serial primary key,
  message_id bigint unique not null,
  message_type varchar(255) not null -- this isn't necessarily unique
);
```

How can I accomplish this? Sure, `message_id` will always be unique, but there could be many messages with `message_type = 'start_message'`

Comment: Which is why I don't see this working as you can't determine the conflict

Comment: I don't understand the requirement. There can be several rows with the same `message_type`, so with which row does the `INSERT` conflict?

Comment: A `chat_message` can serve multiple purposes, for instance it can be a 'start_message' and a `keyboard_message` (a type of message that responds with a keyboard). A `chat_message` that is a `keyboard_message` can have its `message_id` value changed in the future. Also, there are different conversations that have messages that are `start_message`s, so I can't put a `unique` constraint on it

Comment: The only thing I could think of if to first fetch for a record, check for whether or not it exists, and then proceed to update. But that seems like I'm adding an extra unnecessary request